# my builds are disappearing in windows 10 minecraft bedrock

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

chunks of my world went away for no reason, but it was just the parts of the chunks that I built/destroyed. the natural generation stayed the same. I have no clue what happened

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As this seems to be an unknown issue, I recommend making a bug report on [Mojang's Bug Tracker](https://bugs.mojang.com/projects/MCPE/summary). Outside of that, the best course of action would probably be to start backing up your worlds.

Comment: The dupe doesn't actually answer it. The only answer is a wild guess.